# Payment page place order disabled while trying to set the creditcard as default payment method

Tags: magento2, payment-methods, braintree

I am trying to set the credit card as pre-selected payment method and is working fine like when i load payment page the credit card payment method is shows selected, but the place order is disabled and not able to place order.

> When the payment info page loads, I "Checked" the already "Checked" radio button for the credit card. As soon as I checked it, the "Place Order" button became active. Means, when the page loads, it's showing the options as already checked. But when I click on it, it 'checks it' for real. And then it works.

Comment: Please help, if any one have solution for this.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't specify how you implemented select default payment method

You can try to use following way to select default payment

**app/code/Acme/StackExchange/view/frontend/requirejs-config.js**

```js
let config = {
    config: {
        mixins: {
            'Magento_Checkout/js/model/checkout-data-resolver': {
                'Acme_StackExchange/js/model/checkout-data-resolver-mixin': true
            }
        }
    }
};
```

**app/code/Acme/StackExchange/view/frontend/web/js/model/checkout-data-resolver-mixin.js**

```js
define([
    'jquery',
    'mage/utils/wrapper',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/checkout-data',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/model/payment-service'
], function ($, wrapper, checkoutData, paymentService) {
    'use strict';

    return function (resolver) {
        resolver.resolvePaymentMethod = wrapper.wrap(resolver.resolvePaymentMethod, function (_super) {
            let availablePaymentMethods = paymentService.getAvailablePaymentMethods(),
                selectedPaymentMethod = checkoutData.getSelectedPaymentMethod(),
                defaultPaymentMethod = 'cashondelivery';
            if (!selectedPaymentMethod) {
                availablePaymentMethods.some(function (payment) {
                    if (payment.method == defaultPaymentMethod) {
                        checkoutData.setSelectedPaymentMethod(defaultPaymentMethod);
                    }
                });
            }

            _super();
        });

        return resolver;
    };
});
```